# Exception error in Visual Basic 2013

Tags: c#, csv, exception

I try to run code using C# from http://dynamicnotions.blogspot.com/2008/09/training-neural-networks-using-back.html but it give an error while running and give this message

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred.

I have try fix the error but another error will appear. Can anybody help me find the problem occurred in this code?

```
public Pattern(string value, int inputSize)
{
    string[] line = value.Split(',');
    if (line.Length - 1 != inputSize)
        throw new Exception("Input does not match network configuration"); //error occur
    _inputs = new double[inputSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < inputSize; i++)
    {
        _inputs[i] = double.Parse(line[i]);
    }
    _output = double.Parse(line[inputSize]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see for a `System.Exception` to be thrown is from the lines:

```
if (line.Length - 1 != inputSize)
    throw new Exception("Input does not match network configuration"); //error occur
```

This probably means that the number of columns you say you have in your CSV `int inputSize` does not match the number of columns actually found in `value` by splitting on comma characters.

```
string[] line = value.Split(',');
```

Check your CSV file to make sure it has the same number of columns that you specify.

Note too that commas in the data itself, if not properly handled, can throw this off.  For example, if you have a CSV with columns FirstName and LastName, adding "John,Smith,Jr" will make it seem like there's an extra column.

Comment: For that matter, the calls to `double.Parse` could throw, as could the `new`, though I'd expect to see a different exception type in that case.

Comment: @codingthewheel: That would be a System.FormatException, not System.Exception.

Comment: As I said, I'd expect to see a different exception type in that case. : )